# JSON delimiter tool

Tags: json

I have a series of JSON objects and I need to replace all the commas at the end of each object with a pipe `|`

Obviously I can't use Find & Replace because that would replace every comma in the JSON, but I only want to replace those at the end of each object.

For example:

```
{
 "id":123,
 "name":Joe,
 "last":Smith

} ,                <----- I want to replace this comma only

{"id":454
 "name":Bill,
 "last":Smith
}
```

Comment: If this a programming question (i.e. you're writing code to do the job) you should add tags to identify the language.

Comment: It's not a programming question. I was more or less asking if there was some kind of online tool that could do it for me.

I only know SQL and that's not going to do it so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could parse the JSON by adding '[]' around it and then re-serialize it.

With a PHP script you could do something like this:

```
$content = file_get_contents('/path/to/yourfile.json');

// Add [] around the JSON to make it valid:
$json = json_decode('[' . $json . ']', true);

$result = '';
foreach ($json as $j) {
    if ($result != '') $result .= '|';
    $result .= json_encode($j);
}

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is already a PHP solution.  Here's a Regex solution in case.

```
string s1 = "{\"id\":123,\"name\":Joe,\"last\":Smith} , {\"id\":454,\"name\":Bill,\"last\":Smith}";
string pattern = "} , {";

var s2 = Regex.Split(s1, pattern);
string s3 = string.Join(" | ", s2);
```